# Can I add specific data to an attribute of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I know the below code is not correct, but I thought it would show the intention. Is this possible to do? I want this function to update the original array, with all orderno being in the format 000.0.000.00000.0.

```
let cars= [ 
  {orderno: "5766302385925", make: "Alfa", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "4663873261390", make: "Merc", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "8458821291579" , make: "BMW", dealership: "EU"},
  {orderno: "3376768687480", make: "Ford", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "5186132840921", make: "Buick", dealership: "EU"},
];

function addOrderDot() {
    for (var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
    cars.orderno[i].splice(2,0,'.')
    cars.orderno[i].splice(3,0,'.')
    cars.orderno[i].splice(6,0,'.')
    cars.orderno[i].splice(11,0,'.')
    } 
}
```

Desired array after function:

```
let cars= [ 
  {orderno: "576.6.302.38592.5", make: "Alfa", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "466.3.873.26139.0", make: "Merc", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "845.8.821.29157.9" , make: "BMW", dealership: "EU"},
  {orderno: "337.6.768.68748.0", make: "Ford", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "518.6.132.84092.1", make: "Buick", dealership: "EU"},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```js
let cars= [ 
  {orderno: "5766302385925", make: "Alfa", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "4663873261390", make: "Merc", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "8458821291579", make: "BMW", dealership: "EU"},
  {orderno: "3376768687480", make: "Ford", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "5186132840921", make: "Buick", dealership: "EU"},
];

function addOrderDot(cars) {
  return cars.map(car => ({
    ...car,
    orderno: car.orderno.slice(0, 3) + '.' +
      car.orderno.slice(3, 4) + '.' +
      car.orderno.slice(4, 7) + '.' +
      car.orderno.slice(7, 12) + '.' +
      car.orderno.slice(12, 13)
  }));
}

let result = addOrderDot(cars);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify your array in place, so you need to

1. iterate over all the elements of the array
2. take the value of the orderno property of the element
3. modify the value
4. update back the orderno property of element on the array

---

(1) iterate over all the elements of the array

there are different possibilities, the simplest technique is to loop with a `for`, the same way you already tried

```
 for (let i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
 }
```

(2) you address the element of the array using `cars[i]`, and access the `errorno` property with `cars[i].orderno`

```
 let orn = cars[i].orderno;
```

(3) modify its value

```
orn = orn.slice(0,3)+'.'+orn.slice(3,4);
```

(4) assign directly the new value on the array

```
cars[i].orderno = orn;
```

So, putting all pieces together

```
 for (var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
    let orn = cars[i].orderno;
    orn = orn.slice(0,2)+'.'+orn.slice(2,4) ;
    cars[i].orderno = orn;
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate you wringing out the thought process so much. This has really helped my understanding :) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to use a simple regular expression to replace each string:

```
let cars= [ 
  {orderno: "5766302385925", make: "Alfa", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "4663873261390", make: "Merc", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "8458821291579" , make: "BMW", dealership: "EU"},
  {orderno: "3376768687480", make: "Ford", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "5186132840921", make: "Buick", dealership: "EU"},
];

function addOrderDot() {
    cars.forEach(car => {
       car.orderno = car.orderno.replace(
      /^(.{3})(.{1})(.{3})(.{5})(.{1})$/,
      `$1.$2.$3.$4.$5`
    )
    })
}
```

Explanation: We iterate through the elements of the cars array and logically group the orderno digits into 5 groups.

In regExp ^ means the beggining of the string, () a defines logical group that we can later use as a variable, .{number} a number of characters, and $ the end of the string.
So our regexp separates a group of 3 chars as $1, a group of 1 char as $2 and so on.
Then we just replace the initial string with the "stitched" logical groups.

RegExp might seem a little confusing at first, but can be a great tool when dealing with strings and obvious patterns.

Comment: This is very cool. Thanks man!!! I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of help. Make sure you accept an answer as best fitting, for future searchers to spot!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can use map to transform array:

```js
let cars= [ 
  {orderno: "5766302385925", make: "Alfa", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "4663873261390", make: "Merc", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "8458821291579" , make: "BMW", dealership: "EU"},
  {orderno: "3376768687480", make: "Ford", dealership: "NA"},
  {orderno: "5186132840921", make: "Buick", dealership: "EU"},
];

console.log(cars.map(car => {car.orderno = "test"; return car}))
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this is useful. Do you know how I can implement it via the function above, so It auto updates the order numbers?